# URL redirects to subdomain when updating page from wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have site hosted in `http://blog.example.com` now i have moved it to location `http://blog.example.com/myblog` folder. Have changed site location from `wp-options` table and it works fine in new locaiton. but my problem is that when i update any page or post from admin panel, page redirects to `http://blog.example.com` url. I am not able to update that page.

**Note**: I have used visual composer for page editor.

Pls suggest me setting that i need to change.

Comment: Have you gone through this ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Yes i did changes as suggested in site but problem is as it was

Comment: Just facing issue when updating page.

Comment: Do the changes you make to the page get saved before redirection?

Comment: Nope, page can not be changed bcos it redirects before updating database

Comment: Is there any issue in virtual composer plugin?

Comment: @Downvotter, Can you pls comment reason for downvote? Its really a rude behavior to down vote without mentioning any reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an export of your database and find and replace http://blog.example.com with http://blog.example.com/myblog in your favorite text editor to make sure that all mentions of the old URL have been removed.

Afterwards you can also find and replace http://blog.example.com/myblog/myblog with http://blog.example.com/myblog to change URL's that were already changed back.